# Power Automate Flow Dataverse Connector Delete trigger - customize Body fields

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, dataverse

I am using the Dataverse connector for Microsoft Flow. I am using the [Delete trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/commondataserviceforapps/#when-a-row-is-added,-modified-or-deleted) to run my flow whe a row is deleted. I then would like to call an 3rd party API, but I need other fields from the row being deleted than is provided in the body of the delete trigger.

For example, the delete trigger body has the following:

```
{
  "id": "<guid>",
  "ItemInternalId": "<guid>",
  "SdkMessage": "Delete",
  "RunAsSystemUserId": "<guid>"
}
```

But I need field `someotherfield` from this *Entity Table* in my logic. But I can't query it from the "id" field, because the row was just deleted.  Can I customize what is passed in the body somehow?

Comment: I reckon you've got two options, 1) speak to Microsoft and ask the question or 2) save all of your data into another table and then when the deletion happens, you can refer to the backup table for all of the relevant data and then delete it on the way through as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the body. Are the rows being deleted via the Maker Portal, or through an app/flow? If so, you could send the required information to your flow before actually removing the row. It all depends on where you want to do that.

You can enforce people to not remove manually, by taking away their delete rights btw.

Comment: Being deleted from a CE app